# Instagram force touch menu on Android

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, instagram, popupmenu

Instagram on Android recently add new feature, when user long click to items at the Browse section, a popup menu shows and allow user to pre-view photo/video instead of going to its details.
It is really cool like iOS force touch feature.
Does anyone know any idea how we can do the same on Android app? 
Can we just use Context Menu or Overlay Window to do that?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use a DialogFragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: They do not release the touch and keep view inside current screen, do you think DialogFragment can do that?

Comment: have you had any luck ?!

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi Not yet, do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you found any perfect solution? @BobbyTran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can do quite the same on UI with this library

https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment

But the thing is:
When I long press the button, I have to RELEASE my finger to continue touching the dialog fragment. The touch event is still sent to activity not DialogFragment.

Do you know how to pass touch event / focus to dialog fragment right after it is showed?

Comment: The last one is an excelent question. I'm wondering the same. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's the closest library I've found on the internet,

https://github.com/nantaphop/HoverTouchView

it might not be exactly like IG's, but for sure it gives the idea

Answer (score 1):

I Have found 3DTouch as well as in Instagrame.

This library is hosted on Jitpack.io, which means to use it you will have to add the following to your root build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

And then you will need to add the following dependency to your applications build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.shalskar:PeekAndPop:v1.0.1'
}
```

**Usage:**

Basic usage is easy, simply provide an activity instance, a layout resource for the peek and pop and 1 or more views that will show the peek and pop when long clicked.

```
PeekAndPop peekAndPop = new PeekAndPop.Builder(this)
                .peekLayout(R.layout.peek_view)
                .longClickViews(view)
                .build();
```

You can get the peek view by calling getPeekView() on the PeekAndPop object, and use findViewById() to get access any views in the peek layout.

```
View peekView = peekAndPop.getPeekView();
ImageView imageView = peekView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
TextView textView = peekView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

Often you will want to have the peek and pop shown when an item in a list (or other scrollable view) is clicked on, to ensure the peek and pop works correctly, you will have to add this line of code:

```
        .parentViewGroupToDisallowTouchEvents(viewGroup)
```